# Access Violation for Notification

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Getting a strange Access Violation that I can't track down.  Seems to happen almost randomly when users are using the program.

Using madexcept, it shows the stack trace:

```
date/time          : 2014-09-17, 18:04:30, 366ms
operating system   : Windows 8 x64 build 9200
system language    : English
system up time     : 3 days 19 hours
program up time    : 1 hour
processors         : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz
physical memory    : 3113/6036 MB (free/total)
free disk space    : (C:) 562.61 GB
display mode       : 1366x768, 32 bit
process id         : $24d0
allocated memory   : 43.32 MB
largest free block : 1023.78 MB
executable         : MyProgram.exe
exec. date/time    : 2014-09-17 17:03
compiled with      : Delphi XE5
madExcept version  : 4.0.8.1
callstack crc      : $1d6387db, $5509d601, $a3980266
exception number   : 10
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Access violation at address 005A8BE4 in module 'MyProgram.exe'. Read of address 001C7424.

main thread ($1310):
005a8be4 +070 MyProgram.exe Vcl.Controls    5595 +12 TControl.Notification
005ae5cf +00f MyProgram.exe Vcl.Controls    9169  +1 TWinControl.Notification
00667b1b +00f MyProgram.exe Vcl.Forms       3779  +1 TCustomForm.Notification
00537894 +040 MyProgram.exe System.Classes 15856  +8 TComponent.Notification
005376e9 +01d MyProgram.exe System.Classes 15778  +2 TComponent.RemoveComponent
00537445 +029 MyProgram.exe System.Classes 15653  +4 TComponent.Destroy
00538b7f +013 MyProgram.exe System.Classes 16460  +1 TBasicAction.Destroy
00561672 +03a MyProgram.exe System.Actions   485  +4 TContainedAction.Destroy
0058f0b3 +027 MyProgram.exe Vcl.ActnList     228  +3 TCustomAction.Destroy
00408ee0 +008 MyProgram.exe System         15513  +1 TObject.Free
006732fa +082 MyProgram.exe Vcl.Forms      10947 +14 TApplication.SetHint
0067307e +066 MyProgram.exe Vcl.Forms      10863  +4 TApplication.Idle
0067237f +017 MyProgram.exe Vcl.Forms      10318  +1 TApplication.HandleMessage
006726ad +0c9 MyProgram.exe Vcl.Forms      10456 +26 TApplication.Run
0086b12a +39a MyProgram.exe MyProgram       152 +88 initialization
7786919d +00c KERNEL32.DLL                            BaseThreadInitThunk
```

Update:

```
cpu registers:
eax = 740053f8
ebx = 00000001
ecx = 00000001
edx = 00000000
esi = 0253aea0
edi = 025c29c0
eip = 005aca54
esp = 0018fdf0
ebp = 006120a0

stack dump:
0018fdf0  c0 29 5c 02 b0 c9 59 02 - d6 00 00 00 07 b7 53 00  .)\...Y.......S.
0018fe00  01 00 00 00 6c e8 7d 00 - c0 29 5c 02 b0 c9 59 02  ....l.}..)\...Y.
0018fe10  01 00 00 00 f8 c9 5a 00 - b0 c9 59 02 c0 29 5c 02  ......Z...Y..)\.
0018fe20  01 00 00 00 44 24 5b 00 - b0 c9 59 02 c0 29 5c 02  ....D$[...Y..)\.
0018fe30  01 00 00 00 90 b9 66 00 - c0 29 5c 02 20 8d 5c 02  ......f..)\. .\.
0018fe40  00 00 00 00 07 b7 53 00 - 01 fe 18 00 c0 fe 18 00  ......S.........
0018fe50  b0 63 66 00 20 8d 5c 02 - c0 29 5c 02 5c b5 53 00  .cf. .\..)\.\.S.
0018fe60  c0 29 5c 02 c0 29 5c 02 - 00 2a 5c 02 ba b2 53 00  .)\..)\..*\...S.
0018fe70  c0 29 5c 02 00 2a 5c 02 - f4 c9 53 00 00 00 00 00  .)\..*\...S.....
0018fe80  1c ff 18 00 c0 29 5c 02 - 00 fe 18 00 e7 54 56 00  .....)\......TV.
0018fe90  4c 2a 5c 02 c0 29 5c 02 - 01 fe 18 00 28 2f 59 00  L*\..)\.....(/Y.
0018fea0  54 2f 59 00 20 8d 5c 02 - 1f 8f 40 00 6f 71 67 00  T/Y. .\...@.oqg.
0018feb0  77 71 67 00 00 00 00 00 - b0 c9 59 02 c0 29 5c 02  wqg.......Y..)\.
0018fec0  f0 fe 18 00 f3 6e 67 00 - 1c ff 18 00 2c a2 40 00  .....ng.....,.@.
0018fed0  f0 fe 18 00 1c ff 18 00 - 00 00 00 00 20 8d 5c 02  ............ .\.
0018fee0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1c ff 18 00 20 8d 5c 02  ............ .\.
0018fef0  44 ff 18 00 f4 61 67 00 - d8 02 02 00 00 02 00 00  D....ag.........
0018ff00  00 00 00 00 bf 00 6e 02 - ff 6d 56 00 57 02 00 00  ......n..mV.W...
0018ff10  2e 03 00 00 31 65 67 00 - 22 65 67 00 28 ff 18 00  ....1eg."eg.(...
0018ff20  fc 9f 40 00 44 ff 18 00 - 4c ff 18 00 65 65 67 00  ..@.D...L...eeg.

disassembling:
[...]
005aca4a      loc_5aca4a:
005aca4a 5595   mov     eax, [esi+$bc]
005aca50        test    eax, eax
005aca52        jz      loc_5aca5e
005aca52
005aca54      > cmp     edi, [eax+$c]
005aca57        jnz     loc_5aca5e
005aca57
005aca59 5596   xor     edx, edx
005aca5b        mov     [eax+$c], edx
005aca59
005aca5e      loc_5aca5e:
005aca5e 5598   pop     edi
[...]
```

The stacktrace doesn't even include code from my program (apart from the initialization) so I don't know what could be causing it.  The full program is very long and I don't know which part is responsible to make a shorter example.

Edit: Enabled disassembly and got another log - extra information has been added.

Comment: Please show the disassembly too. And tell us the Delphi version, including update number. So we can see the code at Vcl.Controls    5595 +12. In fact the complete madExcept report would help. Since you've not shown your code all we could do is tell you how to debug it.

Comment: I added more of the report - it was Delphi XE5.  If I could figure out which part of the code was relevant, I'd post it.

Comment: Can't you post the full report. I'd love to see the disassembly.

Comment: The full report didn't include disassembly - is that an option that can be enabled?

Comment: Well, like everything in ME, things can be enabled or disabled. Disabling disassembly just makes your life harder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What we can tell from the information is that the error is raised in `TControl.Notification`. That looks like this:

```
procedure TControl.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if Operation = opRemove then
  begin
    if AComponent = PopupMenu then
      PopupMenu := nil
    else if AComponent = Action then
      Action := nil
    else if AComponent = FHostDockSite then
      FHostDockSite := nil
    else if AComponent = FCustomHint then
      FCustomHint := nil
    else if (FTouchManager <> nil) and (AComponent = FTouchManager.GestureManager) then
      FTouchManager.FGestureManager := nil;
  end;
end;
```

You are also told to look at line 5595, which is 12 lines from the start of the function. That line is:

```
else if (FTouchManager <> nil) and (AComponent = FTouchManager.GestureManager) then
```

Now, the obvious explanation for the error is that the read of `FTouchManager` triggered the access violation. That would happen if `Self`, that is the instance on which the method is executed, has already been destroyed.

So, for some reason, this method appears to have been called on an instance that has already been destroyed. We cannot explain that for you, unless you get lucky perhaps and a websearch reveals a problem with the exact same symptoms. What you need to do next is find a way to reliably reproduce the fault, and then work out why it occurs.

One obvious step is to use FastMM in full debug mode. This will make it much more likely that memory accesses on freed objects to indeed lead to access violations. That could very well make the problem occur more predictably, which helps you trace its root cause.

Comment: Any extra insight with the disassembly?

Comment: It's the read of `FTouchManager.GestureManager` that is failing.   `mov     eax, [esi+$bc]
test    eax, eax
jz      loc_5aca5e` is `FTouchManager <> nil` and the next line is where it fails, `cmp     edi, [eax+$c]` Now, at this point `eax` is `FTouchManager`. Either `Self` has been destroyed (and reused) or `GestureManager` has been destroyed. There's not much more that I can offer and I doubt anyone could say very much more with the info here. This is going to take some debugging on your part I think.